# clustering a list of dictionaries according to specific key/value pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Say i have a list of dictionaries that all have the same keys. and i want to regroup these into several lists such that the values for certain attributes of my choosing are equal. here is an example:

Suppose i have the following list of dictionaries:

```
[  {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.1},
   {'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.2},
   {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.3},
   {'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.4},
   {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.5},
   {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.6}]
```

and i want to cluster it according the the keys a and b. Then the output would be the following list of list of dictionaries:

```
 [[{'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.1},
   {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.3}]

   [{'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.2},
    {'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.4}]

   [{'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.5},
    {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.6}]]
```

What is the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort this firstly, then use `itertools.groupby`.You may could try this below:

```
from itertools import groupby

t = [{'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.1},
     {'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.2},
     {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.3},
     {'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.4},
     {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.5},
     {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.6}]

print([[*j] for i, j in groupby(sorted(t, key=lambda x: (x['a'], x['b'])), key=lambda x: (x['a'], x['b']))])
```

Result:

```
[[{'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.1}, {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.3}], [{'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.5}, {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.6}], [{'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.2}, {'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.4}]]
```

If you want to create a function to receive muitlple keys, you could try:

```
from itertools import groupby

def group_by(*args):
    return [[*j] for i, j in groupby(sorted(t, key=itemgetter(*args)), key=itemgetter(*args))]


t = [{'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.1},
     {'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.2},
     {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.3},
     {'a': 0.1, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.4},
     {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.5},
     {'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.7, 'c': 0.6}]

print(group_by('a', 'b'))
```

Comment: @cyrus You could use `*args` to receive them, and use a list comprehension to create a filter.I've updated my answer.